# Custom Error Message for file element

Tags: zend-framework

I am trying to add custom error message to my file element validator. It is working for all the elements, BUT file. Kindly point out where am I going wrong. I know similar question has been asked before but I want to know what is the problem with this code?

```
    $file= new Zend_Form_Element_File('albumcover');
    $file->setAttrib('size',35)
    ->removeDecorator('label')
    ->removeDecorator('htmlTag');

    $file->setRequired(true)
    ->addValidator('Size',true,'1MB')         
    ->addValidator('Count',true,1)
    ->addValidator('IsImage',true,'jpg,jpeg,png'); 
    $file->addErrorMessage("Upload 'jpg,jpeg or png' file of less than 1MB in size");
```

It shows predefined errors not the error message that I have set

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do this in the controller to check if the element has an error and print a specific error message.

```
$form = My_Form_File();
...
if ($form->isValid()) {
...
} else {
    if ($form->getElement('albumcover')->hasErrors()) {
        $form->getElement('albumcover')->addError("Upload 'jpg,jpeg or png' file of less than 1MB in size");
    }
}
```

Though I would recommend letting the user know in the description with

```
$file->setDescription("Upload 'jpg,jpeg or png' file of less than 1MB in size");
```

Comment: But this also displays the default error along with the custom one